# Issue implementing a callback function

Tags: javascript, callback

I working on a set of problems meant to help understand callback functions. I understand that a callback if a function that is called after an event but I'm not sure how it works in this case.

I have a the loop that iterates through the passed in array and runs the encrypt function.

```
const cipher = require('./cipher')

exports.encrypt = function(text, callback) {
  cipher.encrypt(text, callback)
}

exports.decrypt = function(text, callback) {
  cipher.decrypt(text, callback)
}

exports.encryptMultiple = function(textArray, callback) {
  // 1. For each string in the textArray call exports.encrypt to encrypt the string
  // 2. Each encrypt must be run in parallel
  // 3. If one encrypt fails then call the callback immediately with the error as the first parameter
  // 4. If all encrypts succeed then return an array of encrypted strings. They must be in the same order as received.

  //what I have so far
  let encrypted = []

  textArray.forEach(element => {
    encrypted.push(cipher.encrypt(element))
  });

}
```

The expected output is an array of the encrypted values. Currently I'm am receiving an array where each element is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you may want to provide more context in your question.
Secondly, I believe you have got callbacks a bit confused. Callbacks are simply put functions that can be passed to other functions which will execute them. There is a lot more to it but this is the simplest explanation I could provide. From what i understand, you want to execute the callback if there is an exception. This might be what you're looking for.

```
try {
  //Execute your code here.
  cipher.encrypt(element);
}
catch(error) {
  callback();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello the cipher npm which you are using does not take a second parameter [take a look by clicking here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cipher)!. There is no need of using export for the functions used in same file as well please [take a look at export here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/nodejs-module-exports)!.

instead of

```
exports.encrypt = function(text, callback) {
  cipher.encrypt(text, callback)
}

exports.decrypt = function(text, callback) {
  cipher.decrypt(text, callback)
}
```

You can simply implement

```
encrypt = function(text){
 cipher.encrypt(text);
}

decrypt = function(text, callback) {
  cipher.decrypt(text);
}
```

And call these function inside forEach. As for understanding of callbacks consider the below example

```
function doHomework(subject, callback) {
  alert(`Starting my ${subject} homework.`);
  callback();
}
function alertFinished(){
  alert('Finished my homework');
}
doHomework('math', alertFinished);
```

Please refer [click here](https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-the-heck-is-a-callback-aba4da2deced)!